# Aren't there supposed to be MVC 3 controls in the VS 2010 toolbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I've installed ASP.NET MVC3 and the Tools Update, but don't see any MVC3 controls in the Toolbox.

If they are supposed to be there, how do I add them?

If not, why not?

Comment: see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc-4-and-visual-studio-2011/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 or http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4 or http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVC does not have any server controls that come with Visual Studio. It is a completely different paradigm from ASP.NET Forms type development where you use standard HTML controls and control behavior with JavaScript/JQuery. You can extend them with third party controls which are usually in the form of JavaScript libraries.  A good one to start with is [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which is open source and included in the template project that is created for MVC 3.

Comment: Well, another question. How does one know what controls/HtmlHelpers are available for MVC if they're not in the toolbox??

Comment: They are all third party so just Google "mvc controls" and you will get a lot of hits. You can also Google "jquery controls" since it is all based on javascript and html standards. As mentioned before, JQuery UI is a good starting point. Component One has extended this library for a larger set of controls.  Take a look at the Silk Project (http://silk.codeplex.com/) for great examples of best practices and use of JQuery controls in MVC.

Comment: I meant what comes natively with ASP.NET NVC, not 3rd party tools. However, I will look up the Silk Project! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No. MVC doesn't have server controls. A great place to start is [ASP.NET MVC Overview](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview).

Comment: Yes, but the question about server controls. But controls (HtmlHelpers in this case) in general. I doubt Microsoft wants a programmer to memorize all the HtmlHelpers (and whatever else) just because they are not server controls.